# How to get the alias name of a digital certificate stored in a PKCS#11 Crypto token

Tags: c#

I have a crypto token that contains a digital certificate. How to get the alias name of the digital certificate. I am using C# for coding.
For example, if you need the alias name in JAVA , there is a function called 'getalias' which returns all the alias name of the all the digital certificate stored in the crypto token. How do I do that using c#.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`X509Certificate2.FriendlyName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.friendlyname?view=netframework-4.7.2) property which corresponds to the Alias property in X.509. If there is no value then an empty string is returned.

```
X509Certificate2 cert = ...
if( cert.FriendlyName.Length == 0 ) {
    Console.WriteLine( "Certificate has no friendly name" );
}
else {
    Console.WriteLine( "Alias: " + cert.FriendlyName );
}
```